# When kubectl replace might recreate resource?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, argocd

A source file of gitops-engine (an engine used in ArgoCD) contains the following comment:

> Avoid using `kubectl replace` for CRDs since 'replace' might recreate resource and so delete all CRD instances.
> The same thing applies for namespaces, which would delete the namespace as well as everything within it,
> so we want to avoid using `kubectl replace` in that case as well.

(source https://github.com/argoproj/gitops-engine/blob/e56739ceba00848d6e8a6ba8eb935ca3b5c800dc/pkg/sync/sync_context.go#L918-L920)

In what situations the recreation might happen? (Without using the `--force` flag.)

Comment: interesting question ! just trying to go a step further i read this: https://blog.atomist.com/kubernetes-apply-replace-patch/ I believe replace (non forced) is all about not losing any data and for atomic resource changes as the document outlines.

Comment: I have the same feeling :) (But I am not a K8S expert.)

Comment: so do i... glad we are having the same feeling !